# Create multiple new dataframes based on a condition met in old dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr

I have GPS tracking data from multiple projects that used different GPS time interval settings. I would like to interpolate these using the `adehabitatLT` package; however, the `ltraj` object requires all tracks to have the same theoretical GPS intervals. Therefore, I have rounded my median GPS interval time in my data, and would now like to create individual dataframes containing tracks that each share the same GPS interval time.

Essentially, I have a dataframe like this:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(c('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10'), each = 5),
                   var1 = rep(c('1', '3', '4', '5', '5' ), each = 10))
```

And I would like to create multiple new dataframes, with each new dataframe holding the rows that share the same var1 value.

I can do this one by one using e.g. `subset`  . but is it possible to create a `loop` that automatically creates the multiple new dataframes, for example in `dplyr`?

Comment: Hi @userr303287, you can try this : `split(data, data$var1)` or `list2env(split(data, data$var1), envir = .GlobalEnv)` Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy solution using `map` from `purrr` and `filter` from `dplyr` that creates a list object with each of the dataframes.

```r
df_list <- map(unique(data$var1), ~filter(data, var1 == ..1))
```

Example output:

```
> df_list[[1]]
   ID var1
1  B1    1
2  B1    1
3  B1    1
4  B1    1
5  B1    1
6  B2    1
7  B2    1
8  B2    1
9  B2    1
10 B2    1
```